# Guessing game using a random number in a specific range

Tags: javascript

The program is a high-low guessing game where a random number is generated from the specific range that the user inputs and the user has to guess that random number.

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the targetNumber or the currentGuess. The program seems to work fine at first but when I input the the currentGuess number, the dialog box either pops up again or tells me too big try again even when the number is smaller than the range of numbers.

Also I want to make so that the user can't input a decimal number or other characters when entering a targetMax and a targetMin.

```
var keepPlaying = true;
var currentGuess = 0;
var targetMax = null;
var targetMin = null;
var targetNumber = parseInt(targetMin + Math.random()*((targetMax - targetMin)+1));
var turnCounter = 1;

targetMax = prompt("Choose a whole number to set your maximum parameter.");
targetMin = prompt("Choose a whole number to set your minimum parameter.");
while (keepPlaying) {
    //get a valid guess
    do {
        currentGuess = prompt("Please guess a whole number between " +targetMin+ " and " +targetMax+ ".", "");
    }
    while (!((currentGuess > targetMin) && (currentGuess <= targetMax)))
    //handle the guess
    if (currentGuess == targetNumber) {
        alert("YOU'RE RIGHT!!!\n\nIt took you " + turnCounter + " tries to guess the number.");
        keepPlaying = confirm("Do you want to play again?")
        if (!keepPlaying) {
            break; //not needed, just wanted to show how to exit a loop early
        }
        //reset game
        targetNumber = parseInt(targetMin + Math.random()*((targetMax-targetMin)+1));
        turnCounter = 0;
    } else if (currentGuess > targetNumber) {
        alert("Too big, try again.");
    } else if (currentGuess < targetNumber) {
        alert("Too small, try again.");
    } else { //should be inaccessible
        alert("There was an error parsing your guess.");
    }
    //update counter
    turnCounter++;
}
document.write("<h1>Thank you for using my <font color='red'>AWESOME</font>, web-based guessing game.</h1>");
```

Comment: You set your `targetNumber` before you prompt the user for the maximum and minimum parameters. Also, Java is not the same thing as Javascript, and this question has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: @AaronD sounds like the solution, you should submit an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a random floating point number between 0 and 1. As you've determined, you ned to multiply this to get random values between two other numbers. However, in your code you do this *before* you've prompted the user for those values. As a result, you are multiplying by `null`, which results in 0.

If you move that line to after you've prompted the user for the values, you should get the result that you expect.

Comment: actually never mind it worked at first but didn't work afterwards

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more information on what didn't work (what results are you getting?).